# Cannot install MongoDB Community on Apple M1

Tags: mongodb

I have an Apple M1 using macOS Monterey and I am trying to install MongoDB community latest version. After following the documentation on the website I received this error message (note: I am using a Rosetta terminal because M1 chips do not support homebrew). Does anyone know what is happening with this error?  Please help.

What I have tried:

- stopping and restarting the service and again it does not work when I then type "mongo" or "mongosh" I get an error to refuse to connect.
- I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling many times.
- Possible error is the line `Already downloaded: /Users/katejohnson/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/5bd79f1c70119d0cda4b01fc074ad77ad00a7e8dfc9b243016157d9ee7009874--mongosh-1.3.1.bottle_manifest.json` When I download it (see terminal screenshot)

```
 brew services start mongodb-community@5.0
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/katejohnson/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist` exited with 5.
```

[Terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKzR1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Restart your macOS. Run `brew services start mongodb-community@5.0`. It should fix the problem!

[image: Screenshot of mongodb shell running as a service]

The issue is with the `.plist` file that needs to be present in `LaunchAgents` directory for `launchctl` to run mongod service on startup.